# How to reassign a list of tokens back to the doc after preprocessing?

Tags: spacy

I am using Spacy in Python. Using the following code:

```
corpus = []
for doc, context in nlp.pipe(labelled_texts, as_tuples=True):    
    tmp = [t for t in doc if not t.is_punct]
    tmp = [t.lower_ for t in tmp]
    <???>
    corpus.append(doc)
```

... my question is how to reassign 'tmp' back to the document, such that I may proceed with the corpus afterwards.

Comment: Why not convert your `labelled_texts` to lower before converting them to `doc`? The `token` is just a view of the underlying `doc`. It does not make sense to reassign the text in the doc after you have added the annotations to it as it would hurt the integrity of the data. Imagine you had a text "Mark is from France". When you convert the text to a `doc` using `doc = nlp("Mark is from France")`, in this `doc`, the first `token` ("Mark") is `titlecased`. If you reassign the value to `mark`, then you will hurt the integrity of the doc (I am not sure if you can even assign it).

Comment: To make your life easier for preprocessing, use something like [textacy](https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/preprocessing.html) which comes with a lot of goodies to preprocess your texts. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can't modify the text in a Doc. Can you just add your lowercase tokens to the corpus instead? Because it's not clear why you need a Doc (if at all) it's hard to give advice.